# Catalyst App still showing Fund9 and connection in progress

Tags: wallet, catalyst, voting

Fund10 due on 5 Apr, 2023, 13:00

but the catalyst iPhone app is showing Fund9 and connection in progress.

How can I confirm that I could vote for the next round?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Voting app is inactive at the moment. It will receive an update soon in anticipation of a vote before Fund10.

In addition to this, that date for the start of Fund10 is not accurate: there is no specific timeline just yet. Tho they are getting close to the next steps. They have started sharing some information during past two town halls that affect Fund10 outlook. There will be a vote between Fund10 to formally endorse the direction and everything else.